# Python finding a string in a nested tuple

Tags: python

I have a database and I want to be able to search for a name i.e. if the name is Mark Kram it will show the users with that name, I don't need it to be everyone with the name with "Mark" or "Kram" but only the entered string. My current code, just shows every user and not the one I search for?

(Edit based on comments to remove extraneous code)

```
  find = str(input("Enter the name of the employee you would like to search for: "))
  print()
  for find in record:
      print("Employee Name: " + find[0])
      print("Job title: " + find[1])
      #more prints
```

Comment: Are you referring to choice b or c?  It appears that choice b is intended to print all the employee names...

Comment: To choice c, where it asks for an input to search for an employee. B is supposed to show all employees

Comment: @Xrin you have 3 answers now, and your problem seems to be correctly addressed; it would be nice if you accept one of them (click on the grey thick left to the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to lookup for a match on the first item (full name) in each tuple.

```py
elif choice == "c":
    find = str(input("Enter the name of the employee you would like to search for: "))
    print()
    for employee in record:
        if employee[0] == find:
            print("Employee Name: " + employee[0])
            print("Job title: " + employee[1])
            print("Full time: " + employee[2])
            print("Hourly Rate: " + employee[3])
            print("Years of service: " + str(employee[4]))
            print()
```

Your code is a great example to start learning about `class`es.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon how many records, I would take the simple route and iterate through the records looking for the employee's name:

```
empName = "Mark Kram"
for record in records:
  if record[0] == empName:
    print "we found the employee!"
    print record #print the whole employee record
```

Comment: I see, well since there is already an option of adding an employee, the number of records varies. However you've put `for record in records` should it be `for records in record` since i already have record defined

Comment: I used { for record in records } because it reads better... when you are iterating over a list, the singular named var typically comes first and the plural named var typically comes next.

Comment: Also, rather than iterate over all employees to look for a single employee, you should have another database query that returns a single employee.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're iterating over all of your records and printing without any sort of condition. You're also overwriting the query string immediately.

```
elif choice == "c":
    find = str(input("Enter the name of the employee you would like to search for: "))
    print()
    for employee in record:
        if employee[0] == find:
            print("Employee Name: " + employee[0])
            print("Job title: " + employee[1])
            print("Full time: " + employee[2])
            print("Hourly Rate: " + employee[3])
            print("Years of service: " + str(employee[4]))
            print()
```

Comment: I have tried this to be honest, and it just returns blank, i.e. I add two records, search for a name and it shows nothing.

Comment: find[n] needs to be employee[n].

Comment: First step, cut down the whole script which you've entered into a minimal motivating example. So, for example, manually define two 'rows' of your 'table', then just run the finding loop on it. I've also edited my code because I'd forgotten to change some of your `find` instances.

Comment: I did also try employee[n] But still the same result, shows no results.

Comment: I've dropped that code into your script and it works fine for me. Maybe try validating the strings a bit - in particular, getting rid of surrounding whitespace with `"my string".strip()", which might be preventing matches from being found.

Comment: Never mind, I was being silly, the search is case sensitive. Thanks a lot

Comment: The usage of strip is exactly as I've put it there and the documentation is very clear on what it does. Ignore your script. Start from the basics. This is what you want to do https://gist.github.com/clbarnes/53ffc14e26d3adea8dc5 - that works, right? So build on that.

Comment: Glad you found it. To get around that, just set everything to lower (or upper) case for all the comparisons. `if employee[0].lower() == find.lower()`